# Angular $scope and vars from select box confusion

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have setup a system where I can filter displaying some reporting data on button clicks and drop down list selections.

The filtering works well on the button clicks but I am running into trouble with the drop down list.

Setup is as follows:

```
... more buttons above with the same as below
    <div class="col col-center">
        <button class="button button-outline button-positive" ng-click="setMetric('2')">Personal</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-center">
        <button class="button button-outline button-positive" ng-click="setMetric('3')">Business</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="list">
    <label class="item item-input item-select">
        <div class="input-label">
            Area
        </div>
        <select ng-options="z.id as z.zone for z in zones" ng-model="area"></select>
    </label>
</div>

<p>Ref: 1.{{category}}.{{metric}}.0.{{area}}</p> <!-- this updates fine -->

<div ng-show="shouldShow(1.1.1.0.1)" line-chart chart-data="data"></div>
<div ng-show="shouldShow(1.1.1.0.2)" line-chart chart-data="data2"></div>
```

and the controller:

```
    $scope.category = '1';
    $scope.metric = '1';
    $scope.area = '1';

    $scope.zones = [
        {'zone':'National',         'id':'1'},
        {'zone':'QLD',              'id':'2'},
        {'zone':'All other areas',  'id':'3'},
        {'zone':'Affluent',         'id':'4'},
        {'zone':'Mass',             'id':'5'}
    ];

    $scope.setCategory = function(category) {
        $scope.category = category;
    };

    $scope.setMetric = function(metric) {
        $scope.metric = metric;
    };

    $scope.setArea = function(area) {
        $scope.area = area;
    };

    $scope.getArea = function() {
        return $scope.area;
    };

    $scope.shouldShow = function () {
        console.log("1." + $scope.category + "." + $scope.metric + ".0." + $scope.area); // This does not
        switch ("1." + $scope.category + "." + $scope.metric + ".0." + $scope.area) {
            case "1.1.1.0.1":
                return true;
                break;
            case "1.1.1.0.2":
                return true;
                break;
            default: return false;
        }
    };
```

The problem I am running into is that the area var on the page (see the html comment as part of

Ref: 1.{{category}}.{{metric}}.0.{{area}}

) does update but the reference to it in the function shouldShow() does not update.

How am i misunderstanding scope and how do I make this work?

Comment: What are you expecting to see in the divs. Currently nothing is in them?

Comment: They are filled out by a directive. That doesn't matter though because I just want to show/hide the div and I cant read the variable to do so properly.

Comment: So is the issue that the show/hide is not working?

Comment: create a `$scope.selected = {}` on scope and then move all properties on this like `$scope.selected.category`, `$scope.selected.metric`, the problem mostly is your ng-model's doesnt have dot